# How could I perform two action on a button click

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a page with some input fields and a table  and three button play , pause , stop respectively.I want to refresh the table part only when iI press the play button. I want the play button to perform two action one is to run a update query and reload the page only. I when I click on the pause button I want to stop the reloading of the table .And when I press the stop button I want it to run a udate query . I am using codeigniter, MVC architecture. This what I tried and my view page.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">   
<input type="text" size="7" id="IC" name="IC" value="<?php echo set_value('IC',$IC); ?>" />
<input type="text" size="7" id="ID" name="ID" value="<?php echo set_value('ID',$ID); ?>" />
<button type="button" style="width:100px;">PLAY</button>
<button type="button" style="width:100px;">PAUSE</button>
<button type="button" style="width:100px;">STOP</button>
<table>
<tr>
<th> blah </th>
<th> blah </th>
<th> blah </th>
</tr>
//do some  code
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call two js functions at a time on click of button. like a way..

```
function jsfun1()
{
   //do the action here
}

function jsfun2()
{
   //do the action here
}

call both on onclick

<button type="button" style="width:100px;"  onclick="jsfun1(),jsfun2()">play</button>
```

Comment: The question isn't asking about JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks puttu for your response but I have a doubt can I write my queries in the javascript directly. If possible Can u show me how to do it.

Comment: may your new to web development.. You need to call ajax function through  js. and then call backend php functions to do your queries.

Comment: Ya man I am new to web development stil lot I have to learn from u guys. Thanks .

Comment: ask so many questions you need but it should valid.. This forum is to contain for questions only.

Comment: My whole page is getting reload because i am using a <meta> but i want to reload the table only not the whole page.

Comment: your using refresh page at every 300 seconds. So you need only part refresh (i mean table) use ajax call to refresh only required part not whole page.

Answer (score 1):

Do it with javascript.

Just make 2 functions and use onclick-action in Button tag.
`onclick="playButton0(),playButton1()"`

Comment: Don't use intrusive js please ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery framework to do all this things.

blind `.click` function for every button and do stuff with `$.ajax` function

With ajax function you can post values to controller you want and perform a query or something you want.

more info:

http://api.jquery.com/click/

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/